# MAMP include error wp-blog-header.php

Tags: wordpress, mamp, require

I'm trying to use the global $wpdb in a plugin to insert data into one of my tables.
From the docs it sounds like I just need to include wp-blog-header.php
However when I try to do so I'm getting an error.

PHP Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8888/blog/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/submit/pick.php on line 4

My pluginname/submit/pick.php (which is called by AJAX) has the following code

```
<?php
    $p = 'http://localhost:8888/blog/wp-blog-header.php';
    echo $p;
    require($p);
    echo 'hi';
?>
```

If I load the pick.php, I see http://localhost:8888/blog/wp-blog-header.php and that is it.  So it must be failing on the require, as the error log confirms.

The path is correct as I inserted a quick echo into wp-blog-header.php, and copy pasted the output from pick.php into the address bar and it worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include php files via urls. What you'll be including is the EXECUTED OUTPUT of the script. Since it's a full-blown url, there's no difference between your internal require() and someone hitting that url with a browser. All you'll get is the output of the script, which is probably blank/nothing.

Including via urls, even if it's just a local request to your own server, opens a whole can of worms in terms of security holes.

Any reason you can't simply include it via a normal local file request, e.g.

```
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

?